# children of children in jquery animation stays immobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery animation on 100% width and 100% height containers and the children that are position absolute moves with the container but the child of child with two time position absolute doesn't move, why is that? How can you get around it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hash = location.hash;
  console.log(hash);
  $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    hash = hash ? hash : "#page1";
    $(hash)
      //I have tried adding
      //.css("overflow","hidden");
      .animate({
        height: "hide"
      });
    hash = location.hash
    $(hash)
      //I have tried adding
      //.css("overflow","hidden");
      .animate({
        height: "show"
      });
  });
  hash ? $(hash).toggleClass("page-active") : $("#page1").toggleClass("page-active");
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.page1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.page2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.page-active {
  display: block;
}

a {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.hello {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  left: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="page1" id="page1">
    hello
    <div class="hello">
      <div class="i-stay">
        Why am I here
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#page2">go to page2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="page2" id="page2">
    hi
    <a href="#page1">go to page1</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

here is [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eL0fd1z3/7/)

Comment: I don't understand, which element won't move?

Answer (score 0):

It's a result of the css you've applied, `position: absolute` is an absolute position relative to the nearest parent with a `position: relative`. The link moves because it's absolute but uses a position of `top: 50%;`. Now, look at the code for the object that doesn't move...

```
.hello {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    left: 3em;
}
```

...3em is 3em no matter how tall or wide your parent element is.